# Python - Read text file to String

Tags: python, hex

I have the following python sript, which double hashes a hex value:

```
import hashlib
linestring = open('block_header.txt', 'r').read()
header_hex = linestring.encode("hex") // Problem!!!
print header_hex
header_bin = header_hex.decode('hex')
hash = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(header_bin).digest()).digest()

hash.encode('hex_codec')
print hash[::-1].encode('hex_codec')
```

My text file "block_header.txt" (hex) looks like this:

> 0100000081cd02ab7e569e8bcd9317e2fe99f2de44d49ab2b8851ba4a308000000000000e320b6c2fffc8d750423db8b1eb942ae710e951ed797f7affc8892b0f1fc122bc7f5d74df2b9441a42a14695

Unfortunately, the result from printing the variable header_hex looks like this (not like the txt file):

> 303130303030303038316364303261623765353639653862636439333137653266653939663264653434643439616232623838353162613461333038303030303030303030303030653332306236633266666663386437353034323364623862316562393432616537313065393531656437393766376166666338383932623066316663313232626337663564373464663262393434316134326131343639350a

I think the problem is in this line:

```
header_hex = linestring.encode("hex")
```

If I remove the ".encode("hex")"-part, then I get the error

> unhandled TypeError "Odd-length string"

Can anyone give me a hint what might be wrong?
Thank you a lot :)

Comment: What happens if you do a `linestring = linestring.strip()` before passing it to the encoder? You might have some whitespaces/EOF's in the read string.

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to `header_hex = linestring.encode("hex")` at the beginning.  Like others said, `strip()` and then **decode**.

Comment: Just decode and the last part of the answer qill do what you want http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/5679

Answer (score 1):

You're doing too much encoding/decoding.

Like others mentioned, if your input data is hex, then it's a good idea to strip leading / trailing whitespace with `strip()`.

Then, you can use `decode('hex')` to turn the hex ASCII into binary.  After performing whatever hashing you want, you'll have the binary digest.

If you want to be able to "see" that digest, you can turn it back into hex with `encode('hex')`.

The following code works on your input file with any kinds of whitespace added at the beginning or end.

```
import hashlib

def multi_sha256(data, iterations):
    for i in xrange(iterations):
        data = hashlib.sha256(data).digest()
    return data

with open('block_header.txt', 'r') as f:
    hdr = f.read().strip().decode('hex')
    _hash = multi_sha256(hdr, 2)

    # Print the hash (in hex)
    print 'Hash (hex):', _hash.encode('hex')

    # Save the hash to a hex file
    open('block_header_hash.hex', 'w').write(_hash.encode('hex'))

    # Save the hash to a binary file
    open('block_header_hash.bin', 'wb').write(_hash)
```

Comment: If I substitute the `block_header.txt` code block with my own defined property `header_hex` which contains six typical header fields `Version, hashPrevBlock, hashMerkleRoot, Time, Bits, Nonce` I get a `"Undefined variable 'xrange'"` error as well as a `"Unused variable 'i'"` error. Why would that be? Is it because this xrange loop type is meant for a single hash string?